# Input coming from the standard input and storing as a vector,

Tags: java

```
Background info:
----------------------------------------------------------------
public class Point {

    protected int x;
    protected int y;

    public Point(){

        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public String toString(){

        return "" + x + " , " + y; 
    }
}
---------------------------------------------------------------
public class PointName extends Point {

    private String name;

    public PointName(String name, int x, int y){

        super();
        this.name = name;
    }

    public PointName() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }


    public String toString(){

        return name + super.toString();

    }

}
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I want to create an application called closest point and in this class data is supplied from the standard input(keyboard). Then i want to supply 10 points (name given points) which will be stored in a vector. Then print them out. A bit more after this but im stuck in this stage as i dont know what to do. I welcome all possible solutions!!

**MY SOLUTION SO FAR:**

```
public class ClosestPoint {

    public static void main (String[] args){

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Write in the new point starting with name then x, y");

        String name = "";
        Integer x = 0;
        Integer y = 0;

        String nameGivenPoints[] = null; // List of points to create
        String line = in.nextLine(); // info from the board

        while(!line.endsWith("")){
        nameGivenPoints = line.split("\r\n\r");

        name = nameGivenPoints[0];
        x = Integer.parseInt(nameGivenPoints[1]);
        y = Integer.parseInt(nameGivenPoints[2]);

// Maybe a forloop here
        PointName tenDifferentPunkts = new PointName(name, x, y);
        System.out.println(tenDifferentPunkts.toString());
         line = in.nextLine();

                }   
        }
```

Comment: Your Point constructor appears to be missing some parameters. And what is this Punkt class that PointName extends?

Comment: I had to retype from swedish to english hehe..Punkt is point:) Ok..but i dont need this parameters in the point class as these paremeters are coming from the subclass?

Comment: No, you need the parameters still. Otherwise x evaluates to this.x, so you end up with `this.x=this.x; this.y=this.y;`. Java already has a Point class http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Point.html.

Comment: Your way of reading from System.in doesn't make much sense. How do you expect the user to enter the points?

Comment: @JBNizet: From in.nextLine() method and then split the line(s) to get the name given points( with the name and then x and y coordinates)...any help on what to do????

Comment: @JonHulka: Ok thanks for that! How can i solve the latter issue? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

PointName.java:

```
public class PointName extends java.awt.Point
{

    private String name;

    public PointName(String name, int x, int y)
    {
        super(x,y);
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        return this.name + " : " + super.toString(); 
    }
}
```

ClosestPoint.java:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ClosestPoint
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        String line;
        boolean done=false;
        String error=null;
        List<PointName> points=new ArrayList<PointName>();

        do
        {
            System.out.println("Enter a new point in this format: name:x,y");
            line=in.nextLine();
            done=line.equals("");
            if(!done) //Empty line terminates the loop
            {
                String [] parts=line.split(":");
                if(parts.length==2)
                {
                    String name=parts[0];
                    parts=parts[1].split(",");
                    if(parts.length==2)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            PointName pn=new PointName(name,Integer.parseInt(parts[0]),Integer.parseInt(parts[1]));
                            points.add(pn);
                        }
                        catch(NumberFormatException ex)
                        {
                            error=ex.getMessage();
                        }
                    }else error="Invalid format";
                }else error="Invalid format";
            }
            if(!done) done=error!=null; //If there was an error exit the loop
        }while(!done); //Keep going until something sets the done flag
        if(error!=null)
        {
            System.out.println("Error: "+error);
        }
        else
        {
            //The points are all stored in the points List object now - this just iterates through and prints them out
            System.out.println("Here are the points you entered:");
            for(PointName pn : points)
            {
                System.out.println(pn.toString());
            }
        }
    } 
}
```